# Metadata extension in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, tags, metadata

Is there an in built mechanism to tag extra metadata to HDFS files and retrieve the files based on the tagged information? Say if I want to add an enterprise level information to the data, would it be possible in Hadoop or do we need other frameworks

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful to you

QueryIO provides advanced manual and automated data tagging feature which allows you to define properties for files as they are being written to HDFS. It automatically stores the basic MetaData files stored in HDFS and further extends the MetaData layer by enabling you to define additional MetaData. It understands dozens of file formats such as pdf/xls/doc file formats, image files, audio and video files, etc.

http://www.slideshare.net/QueryIO/hadoop-data-tagging-and-metadata-extension